# Javascript Validation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The validation Of Budget Range is not working in the below code. It Brings Different Results at different point of time.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Budget Range
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="start">
                <option value="">---Select---</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1000000">10 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="2500000">25 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="5000000">50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="7500000">75 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="10000000">1 Crore</option>
                <option value="12500000">1 Crore 25 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="15000000">1 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="17500000">1 Crore 75 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="20000000">2 Crore</option>
                <option value="25000000">2 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="30000000">3 Crore</option>
                <option value="35000000">3 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="40000000">4 Crore</option>
                <option value="45000000">4 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
            </select>
            to
            <select id="end" onchange="selectRange()">
                <option value="0">---Select---</option>
                <option value="1000000">10 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="2500000">25 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="5000000">50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="7500000">75 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="10000000">1 Crore</option>
                <option value="12500000">1 Crore 25 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="15000000">1 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="17500000">1 Crore 75 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="20000000">2 Crore</option>
                <option value="25000000">2 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="30000000">3 Crore</option>
                <option value="35000000">3 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
                <option value="40000000">4 Crore</option>
                <option value="45000000">4 Crore 50 Lakhs</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>

    function selectRange() {
        $startRange = document.getElementById('start').value;
        $endRange = document.getElementById('end').value;

        alert($startRange);
        alert($endRange);

        alert($startRange > $endRange);

        if ($startRange > $endRange) {
            alert('The Budget End Should be Greater than Budget Start');
            $endRange = document.getElementById('end').value = 0;
            return false
        }
    }
</script>
```

The validation Of Budget Range is not working in the above code. It Brings Different Results at different point of time.

Comment: What exactly happens? How is selectRange called?

Comment: Simple When the budget start range is more than budget end it should send a alert message but that is not working

Comment: Please elaborate "different points of time". Is there a way to reproduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are getting value these are coming as string or your comparison is based on string value, so it is producing wrong result.  cast them to number will help.
just replace  these line of code

```
$startRange = document.getElementById('start').value;
$endRange = document.getElementById('end').value;
```

to

```
$startRange = parseInt(document.getElementById('start').value,10);
$endRange = parseInt(document.getElementById('end').value, 10);
```

or

```
$startRange = Number(document.getElementById('start').value);
$endRange = Number(document.getElementById('end').value);
```

and check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QWLEW/2/ using parseInt function

or check this http://jsfiddle.net/QWLEW/3/ using Number function

Comment: Bulls Eye Its Working Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property of select elements returns a string on getting. When you compare them, they will be compared alphabetically, i.e. `"5000000" > "45000000"`. Convert them to numbers before by using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or by [implicit conversion with `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29).

```
if (+$startRange > +$endRange)
```

Btw, JavaScript variables do not need to start with `$`.